# Activrecord timestamp wrong assignment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

for the following:

```
         updated_at         |         created_at         |   id    
----------------------------+----------------------------+---------
 2016-08-26 12:33:35.900201 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.782502 | 2951380
 2016-08-26 12:33:35.916025 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.781838 | 2951379
 2016-08-25 12:33:13.684854 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.684854 | 2951377
 2016-08-25 12:33:13.684753 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.684753 | 2951378
 2016-08-25 12:33:13.652293 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.652293 | 2951376
 2016-08-26 12:32:59.669535 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.589147 | 2951375
 2016-08-26 12:32:59.680676 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.556841 | 2951374
 2016-08-26 12:32:59.559429 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.496964 | 2951373
 2016-08-26 12:32:59.573863 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.461594 | 2951372
 2016-08-26 12:31:10.338129 | 2016-08-25 12:33:13.400724 | 2951371
```

ID `2951378` has an earlier `created_at (and updated_at)` than the `2951377` record!

Anyone have any idea how that may happen, this records inserted by Queue worker handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine several transactions that are occurring simultaneously. They all need auto-generated ids. But the database cannot reserve the same ids for each transaction, because if they all succeed, they will override each other on commit.

So, each transaction gets its own set of auto-incremented values. Transaction A might start before transaction B, and get some ids allocated, but then B finishes first and it's larger IDs get saved with an earlier time.

It's not a sign of any error. It is a reminder that you should never assume the order of auto-generated IDs correlates to the sequence of events in a DB.

Comment: i added also an answer explaining what my exactly happen in this situation, but you answer totally correct though.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like Rails calculates the timestamps, rather than relying on the database to do so

`https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/55dfa009769962367c58563480c9f776ae0f53ea/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L120`

so it makes sense that this kind of situation can happen when multiple workers are saving records at the same time.